# Request dialog - How to get the sender id

Tags: facebook

I'm using this below code so that i get hte request id when my friends accepts my invite but how do i get my uid.

Say I'm A.A sends invite to b.When b ,accepts ,i can get  request id but how do i get A UID

```
 //get the request ids from the query parameter
  $request_ids = explode(',', $_REQUEST['request_ids']);

 //build the full_request_id from request_id and user_id 
 function build_full_request_id($request_id, $user_id) {
  return $request_id . '_' . $user_id; 
}

//for each request_id, build the full_request_id and delete request  
foreach ($request_ids as $request_id)
{
  echo ("reqeust_id=".$request_id."<br>");
  $full_request_id = build_full_request_id($request_id, $user_id);  
  echo ("full_request_id=".$full_request_id."<br>");

  try {
     $delete_success = $facebook->api("/$full_request_id",'DELETE');
     if ($delete_success) {
        echo "Successfully deleted " . $full_request_id;}
     else {
       echo "Delete failed".$full_request_id;}
    }          
   catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
   echo "error";}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a GET call to `/{request_id}` you get back the sender and recipient uids

Comment: i have same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153912/is-it-possible-to-get-sender-iduser-to-user-request-on-Facebook    .Please help me too. I didn't understood what you trying to say with your answer

Comment: I'm also got same problem. I get request id by $_GET['resquest_ids']. How can I get sender id who sent request ?

Comment: Access the API and ask for the full details of the request - it's a HTTP GET request to `https://graph.facebook.com/<REQUEST ID HERE>`

Answer (score 0):

Try `$user_id = $facebook->getUser();`

edit: looking back at your code, I see you already use $user_id, so isn't that the ID you need?

Comment: :It is B uid but how to get a UID